# Angular 4 select not updating value in ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an ngIf that uses a value from a select to display or not another select, but when i change the value in first select, the ngIf still use the old value. The code I'm using:

```html
<div class="form-group" >
 <label>First select</label>
 <select name="status" class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="status.status">
  <option *ngFor="let s of listStatus" [selected]="s.id === status.status" [value]="s.id">{{s.text}}</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="status.status === 1">
 <label>Second select</label>
 <select name="blockLevel" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="status.blockLevel">
  <option *ngFor="let s of listBlockedLevel" [selected]="s.id === status.blockLevel" [value]="s.id">{{s.text}}</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

In the component.ts the value is correctly updated. I tried to show the value using {{status.status}} and the value doesn't change.

---

**Solution**

I resolve my problem using ChangeDetectorRef. In the first select i used a method to update the value

```html
<select name="status" class="form-control" [ngModel]="status.status" (ngModelChange)="setStatus($event)">
```

and in ts component i used this

```js
public setStatus(event: any) {
    this.status.status = event;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

in component constructor i used this to import ChangeDetectorRef

```js
private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
```

Answer (score 0):

The select input component changes the id from type number to a string.

**Option 1**
For the second div, use one of the following `*ngIf` options:

`*ngIf="status.status === 1 || status.status === '1'"`

or

`*ngIf="status.status == 1"`

[Working Plunker 1](https://plnkr.co/edit/mYYCq1lwcqS3HKKoOc90?p=preview)

**Option 2 (Recommended)**
If you do not like the idea of the select input changing the `id` to a string, you can use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]` to save the entire `status` object itself and then reference the `id` using `status.id`.

[Working Plunker 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/dUjtQizv13OX5qIVCzSK?p=preview)

Comment: still not working, i tried to display the value using this `{{status.status}}` but the value doesn't change, it still the initial value

Comment: I've updated my answer with two working plunkers. In both cases, I'm logging the updated value to the console. It appears to be working fine. Try comparing the plunker to your code to see if you are missing anything.

Comment: The first plunker is an exact copy of your code with just the `===` changed to `==`

Comment: I've updated my plunkers to include binding using `{{status.status}}` within the template

Comment: thanks for your answer, but for me still not working, i'm trying another possibilities. The difference i can see is you used Model Driven and i'm using Template Driven.